# I want to do Message transformations in Datapower instead of IIB?

Tags: ibm-datapower, ibm-integration-bus

I want to do message transformation in Datapower instead of IIB. earlier we are using xml to Soap conversion in Handler and sending to IIB. But as per current requirement I need to remove handler and do message conversion in Data Power itself. Please help me if you have sample code and any suggestions on this requirement. Also I need to prepare facade for this requirement. Asking me to prepare POC also.

I am gathering information as xml and xslt code need to use for message transformations in DataPower XI52

expected out put would be removal of handler and in place of it need to use datapower.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

If you are only doing XML transformation XSLT will work fine. In IIB toolkit you can even use the Data Mapper to produce XSLT. NB! DataPower only supports version 1.0 of XSLT!
Else there's a lot tools to build XSLT, e.g. Altova Mapper.

Another option is to use ITX (IBM Transformation Extender) but that requires either Integration module or B2B Module on your DataPower. And the ITX Design Studio (which is a separate license).

Third option is to use Gatewayscript, which also can handle non-XML data...